# IE does not load full image

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, drupal

I am having issue in IE browser. When i browse my site from IE8 , it does not load full image. But for all other browser it work fine. This is drupal theme. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

[Link](http://0828.lebouquet.vincentdemers.info:4772/en/mixed-bouquet)

[image: IE8 Screenshot]

Comment: IE8 doesn't support media queries which I assume your theme has, given that most modern themes do.

Comment: http://0828.lebouquet.vincentdemers.info:4772/en/mixed-bouquet

Comment: You can check that link.

Comment: Can you provide the web page URL? Without any code, it is unlikely to find the root cause.

Comment: http://0828.lebouquet.vincentdemers.info:4772/en/mixed-bouquet

Comment: There are so many modern css techniques that do not work well with IE, this is seen to be a problem with the template and it is more effective sending this question to the creator of the theme to see if it is compatible with IE 8

Comment: I apply old css to my theme. This work well in google chrome but in ie does not load full image.

Comment: IE8 is obsolete and no more supported by Microsoft [link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsforbusiness/end-of-ie-support) so it is safe to ignore it.

Comment: is there a reason you support IE8? That would be the question you should answer first. If you really need it you should read about *progressive enhancment* or *gracefull degration* and decide what way to go.

Comment: When i increate the height of parent container then the image show but leave space on the top.

Comment: Are you using css3 ? IE8 is not compatible , to check you css attributes you can use this useful site https://caniuse.com/ to see compatibility

Comment: No i am using css that compatible for all browsers.